# Send email from Google Group

Tags: google-workspace, email, google-groups

My company uses Google Apps for Business for our email etc.  We use Groups for forward-facing email addresses, e.g. "software@ourdomain.com" which goes to several people.

Is it possible to SEND email from this group address?  We don't want to buy a new account just for the alias, since we don't need the storage space etc.  Is this possible?  Or is there some other way to use an alias to send mail from a non-existant account?

Answer (score 3):

From web-mail: Settings > Account > Add another address.
From a client: as Ignacio has already said, all main clients allow you to specify a specific "from" address.